# y in DATEADD function does not work for year. Instead I can use yy or year. However m and d works. Why?

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT DATEADD(y, 1, '20160212'); -- using y does not work.
```

Result returned is `'20160213'`. In order to the get the desired result, I have to use either yy or year.

However both:

```
SELECT DATEADD(m, 1, '20160212'); 
SELECT DATEADD(d, 1, '20160212'); --works.
```

Why?

Comment: One of the reasons you should use the **full** names - not the abbreviations! Makes your code much more readable if you have `DATEADD(MONTH, .....)` rather than `DATEADD(m, ....` - does that `m` stand for months or minutes again?? ....

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

```
datepart        Abbreviations
year            yy, yyyy
quarter         qq, q
month           mm, m
dayofyear       dy, y     <--- y is already used for day of year
day             dd, d
week            wk, ww
weekday         dw, w
hour            hh
minute          mi, n
second          ss, s
millisecond     ms
microsecond     mcs
nanosecond      ns
```

If you'll notice on your first example, the date increases by one day, which would be expected when adding one "day of year".